# 3 floating divs with center dynamic width

Tags: css, html

Alright so my problem is that I can't get the center div to dynamically set its width based on browser width and still float in between the two divs.

```
<style type="text/css">
#container{width:100%;}
#left{min-height:70px;width:60px;float:left;}
#middle{min-height:70px;width:100%;float:left;}
#right{min-height:70px;width:60px;float:right;}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">text</div>
    <div id="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla enim eget augue pretium facilisis. Quisque euismod mauris eu odio tincidunt pharetra interdum enim dignissim. Phasellus eleifend viverra diam, et vestibulum orci feugiat vitae. Fusce rhoncus, dolor sit amet rhoncus pulvinar, elit libero tincidunt tortor, non elementum lacus nisl sit amet lorem.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur fringilla enim eget augue pretium facilisis. Quisque euismod mauris eu odio tincidunt pharetra interdum enim dignissim. Phasellus eleifend viverra diam, et vestibulum orci feugiat vitae. Fusce rhoncus, dolor sit amet rhoncus pulvinar, elit libero tincidunt tortor, non elementum lacus nisl sit amet lorem.</div>
    <div id="right">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try setting your CSS up like this:

```
#container{width:100%;}
#left{min-height:70px;width:60px;float:left;}
#middle{min-height:70px;padding:0 60px}
#right{min-height:70px;width:60px;float:right;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k87H/)

Comment: Long time later, but was about to ask same, new question. Luckily google helped! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Just a couple notes: instead of the padding on the middle you could instead use overflow:hidden which is a slightly different effect but probably the desired one, and *very* important (as I just spend an hour on this) the floating divs have to be defined before the middle div or else it takes up too much room.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the width of the middle div using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as such:

```
$('#middle').width($('#container').width()-120);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kDLzD/2/)

Comment: And therein lies the problem with CSS. If you have to resort to Javascript to get some layout working, CSS (or the implementation of it, or your understanding of it) is broken. So many people seem to have trouble with it that I think it is CSS which is broken.

Comment: You aren't alone in that sentiment :)

Comment: Yes this would work and i was going to do something like this before and put it in a window.resize() but i didn't want to use js to style this. Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with some trivial javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/SjMqU/

```
var middle = document.getElementById('middle');
var win_width = document.body.offsetWidth;
middle.style.width = (win_width - 140) + 'px';
```

And this fiddle works on window resize: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/SjMqU/4/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to put it into a table, but if you don't want that just make all the divs behave like table cells:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div{display:table-cell;}
  #container{width:100%;}
  #left{min-width:60px;}
  #middle{min-width:50%;}
  #right{min-width:60px;}
</style>
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
#container{width:100%;
}
#left, #middle, #right{min-height:70px; 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#left{width:19%;
    background:red;
}
#middle{width:60%; 
    background:green;
}
#right{width:19%; 
    background:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8BqP9/